# react createElement and invariant errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to adapt this [tabs](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp) to react.
The idea is to add active class for the key clicked with handleclick function

```
class Tabs extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { selected: 0 };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(key, event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      selected: key
    });
  }
  render() {
    var activeClass = this.state.selected === this.props.key ? "active" : "";
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div class="tab">
          <button
            key="1"
            className={"tablinks" + activeClass}
            onClick={this.handleClick}
          >
            London
          </button>
          <button
            key="2"
            className={"tablinks" + activeClass}
            onClick={this.handleClick}
          >
            Paris
          </button>
          <button
            key="3"
            className={"tablinks" + activeClass}
            onClick={this.handleClick}
          >
            Tokyo
          </button>
        </div>
        <div key="1" className={"tabcontent" + activeClass}>
          <h3>London</h3>
          <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
        </div>

        <div key="2" className={"tabcontent" + activeClass}>
          <h3>Paris</h3>
          <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
        </div>

        <div key="3" className={"tabcontent" + activeClass}>
          <h3>Tokyo</h3>
          <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Tabs />, document.querySelector(".container"));
```

but I get two errors:

Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of `Tabs`.

and

Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `Tabs`.

here is the [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/7ebzkv53/6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Fiddle it is not working because the use of React.Fragment.

Anyway, it won't work even with previous corrections because this.props.key does not refer to the good variable.

Try this

```
class Tabs extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { selected: '1' };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

     handleClick (key) {
        this.setState({
            selected: key
        });
    }

    isActive (key) {
        return this.state.selected === key ? 'active' : ''
    }

    render() {
    var activeClass = (this.state.selected === this.props.key ? 'active' : '');
      return (
  <div>
   <div class="tab"> 
    <button className={'tablinks'+ activeClass} onClick={()=>this.handleClick("1")}>London</button>
      <button  className={'tablinks'+ activeClass} onClick={()=>this.handleClick("2")}>Paris</button>
      <button  className={'tablinks'+ activeClass} onClick={()=>this.handleClick("3")}>Tokyo</button>
    </div>
   <div key='1' className={'tabcontent'+ this.isActive('1')}>
    <h3>London</h3>
    <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
  </div>

  <div key='2' className={'tabcontent'+ this.isActive('2')}>
    <h3>Paris</h3>
    <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
  </div>

  <div key='3' className={'tabcontent'+ this.isActive('3')}>
    <h3>Tokyo</h3>
    <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  );
    }
  }
  ReactDOM.render(<Tabs />, document.querySelector('.container'));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `onClick` handler `handleClick` will be passed the event as first argument, not the key. If you want to send the key to the function, you could create an inline function calling `handleClick` with your desired argument.

You are also using an old version of React in your fiddle that doesn't have `React.Fragment` that was introduced in React 16, and the `class` prop on your topmost `div` element should be `className`.

**Example**

```
class Tabs extends React.Component {
  state = { selected: 0 };

  handleClick = key => {
    this.setState({
      selected: key
    });
  };

  render() {
    var activeClass = this.state.selected === this.props.key ? " active" : "";
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="tab">
          <button
            key="1"
            className={"tablinks" + activeClass}
            onClick={() => this.handleClick(1)}
          >
            London
          </button>
          <button
            key="2"
            className={"tablinks" + activeClass}
            onClick={() => this.handleClick(2)}
          >
            Paris
          </button>
          <button
            key="3"
            className={"tablinks" + activeClass}
            onClick={() => this.handleClick(3)}
          >
            Tokyo
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className={"tabcontent" + activeClass}>
          <h3>London</h3>
          <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
        </div>

        <div className={"tabcontent" + activeClass}>
          <h3>Paris</h3>
          <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
        </div>

        <div className={"tabcontent" + activeClass}>
          <h3>Tokyo</h3>
          <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```